# Save joinoutput to a new table from three table joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to save a psql-query into a new table. the psql-query looks like this:

```
select 
(protein.accession, peptide_protein.mutation, peptide_protein.start_position, peptide_protein.end_position, peptide.weight, peptide.sequence)
from peptide
join peptide_protein on peptide_protein.peptide_id = peptide.peptide_id
join organism on organism.organism_id = peptide_protein.organism_id
join protein on peptide_protein.protein_id = protein.protein_id;
```

When i try to do this, i have this sample:

```
CREATE TABLE joinedTables AS
Select 
(protein.accession, peptide_protein.mutation, peptide_protein.start_position, peptide_protein.end_position, peptide.weight, peptide.sequence)
from peptide
join peptide_protein on peptide_protein.peptide_id = peptide.peptide_id
join organism on organism.organism_id = peptide_protein.organism_id
join protein on peptide_protein.protein_id = protein.protein_id
order BY peptide.peptide_id;
```

when i try this, i get the following error:

> ERROR:  column "row" has pseudo-type record

Can someone help me? thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis from your `SELECT` list. Writing a list of columns within parentheses in a `SELECT` list represents them as a `ROW`:

```
CREATE TABLE joinedTables AS
Select 
  protein.accession, peptide_protein.mutation,
  peptide_protein.start_position, peptide_protein.end_position, 
  peptide.weight, peptide.sequence
from peptide
join peptide_protein on peptide_protein.peptide_id = peptide.peptide_id
join organism on organism.organism_id = peptide_protein.organism_id
join protein on peptide_protein.protein_id = protein.protein_id
order BY peptide.peptide_id;
```

Alternatively cast all columns to the same data type, e.g. `text`, or take a look at [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtype.html).